# Elisp: simple wrapper over a «mouse-set-point» changes a behavior

Tags: emacs, elisp, usability

The «mouse-set-point» is a function that is being called in Emacs with "mouse double-click" on a word to set a region around it and activate. I made a simple wrapper over it, and bound instead of the default one, like this:

```
(defun mouse-set-point-highlight-occurs (EVENT)
  (interactive "e")
  (mouse-set-point EVENT))

(global-set-key (kbd "<double-mouse-1>") 'mouse-set-point-highlight-occurs)
```

As you see it does nothing except for plain transfer of an argument, so the behavior shouldn't be changed. But now with double click the region appears just for a moment, and then fades. What could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: you want to call `mouse-set-region` instead of `mouse-set-point`.

The longer answer: part of what you're seeing is a long standing misfeature of the way the mouse region selection code works.  If you look at the code of `mouse-drag-track` (which is the workhorse of `mouse-drag-region` bound to `down-mouse-1`) you'll see that this function is the one that implements the `mouse-set-point` behavior in case of `double-mouse-1` (i.e. it checks if the binding is `mouse-set-point` and if it is, it runs its own code *instead* of `mouse-set-point`).

In Emacs's trunk (i.e. not what will be released as 24.4 but the next one), this code has been modified to work "more normally".  But even in Emacs's trunk, your code won't work right: you'll need to additionally pass a non-nil second argument to `mouse-set-point` in order to indicate that you don't just want to set point, but to actually set the region.

Comment: Hm… So, probably am I supposed to set my function instead of the `mouse-set-point`, right? Like this `(setq mouse-set-point-highlight-occurs 'mouse-set-point)`, and do not change a function that is being called when I do a double click. Is it going to work? Btw, the `mouse-set-region` doesn't worked either.

Comment: Okay, the «setq» doesn't worked. It had never worked with a function pointer in a variables, only with «car» and «cdr». I'd consider it as a bug =.= Anyway, I does a hand-made version of a `mouse-set-region`, and it have an exactly the same problem as the ones I've tried before. Here it is http://pastebin.com/cXdaLhRx Have you an ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say it: in your `mouse-set-point-highlight-occurs`, you need to call `mouse-set-region` instead of `mouse-set-point`.

Comment: That was exactly what I does, and this doesn't worked. Does it works for you?

Comment: In my job PC I have more later version of Emacs than in home, and I tested it here too. Doesn't work either. The problem is exactly the same with disregard what am I call: whether it is `mouse-set-point` or `mouse-set-region`.

Comment: Sorry, I am probably misled you about what I does because the fact that I tested your advice I am mentioned with a muddy phrase «Btw, the `mouse-set-region` doesn't worked either.»

Comment: Hmm, it seems you're right: the `mouset-set-region` in Emacs<=24.4 won't help you either. The code you need to run is not bound to any function, it's hidden in the middle of `mouse-drag-track`.  In Emacs's trunk `mouse-set-region` works, OTOH.

Comment: Stefan, but well, it's not a big problem cuz this is Emacs ☺ Could you say what's wrong with [this hand-made function](pastebin.com/cXdaLhRx) which is supposed to be a replace for buggy at a recent Emacses `mouse-set-region`? It suffers from an exactly the same problem as anything I tried here, and right now it does nothing for except a `mouse-set-region` functionality.

Comment: That's simply because the second `re-search-forward` doesn't move.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works. I am just added the line `(right-char)` before `(re-search-forward…`. If somebody going to suffer of the same problem, you just may give them this code :з